# Domain model doubts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dns

From one side, I want to write a killer app(in ASP.NET MVC) ;)
But from the other side, I have many doubts if I should keep to so called "best practices" at all cost. So I have a **design question** and I really hope you can help me out.

Imagine a standard blog. I want to show 10 most recent posts. My database has standard
`Posts, Categories, Tags, PostTags`
tables. So as a natural consequence, my domain Post class has properties like this:

```
public Category Category { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

I use EF4 with POCO support. And I load the data with a standard query:

```
from p in context.Posts.Include("Category").Include("Tags")
select p
```

But why should I load the entire Post class (with for example those 2 properties), when on the page all I want to show (besides the post itself) are links to category and each tag, so all the columns I need are:
`[Categories].[Name], [Categories].[Slug], [Tags].[Name], [Tags.Slug]`.

I don't need the entire Category or Tag instance (which may have 100 columns in corresponding table in the database)! I imagine that when a site gets a lot of requests, it DOES matter. So it would be nice not to load all columns (avoid scary `SELECT *`).

I thought I can add a new class to my domain, say: ShortPost. But I feel it's not my domain! Post is the model, ShortPost is... well, just part of a complete Post. Besides - this ShortPost feels to me like modyfying/adjusting Domain (Model) just to please the View.

To sum up: **should I really load the entire Model instance when on the View side I don't need the entire object?** Can you please tell me about some preferred solutions/ways/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the complete domain models- That way you can cache them an have the full object in the cache.

It would be confusing to have partly filled objects in the cache.

Comment: OK, that's an answer... but as a counter-argument I'll say: I'm scared that loading complete instances (which would mean e.g. 200 columns from a database) will be veeery slow - and in a webapp performance is pretty important.

Comment: I completely forgot about caching... that will do the trick. Thanks very much for the concept :)

Answer (score 2):

How about not using your Entities for reading? 
This is a characteristic of Command-Query Separation pattern.

If the only fields your View needs are  [Categories].[Name], [Categories].[Slug], [Tags].[Name], [Tags.Slug]

Then create a DTO that represents this and populate it either by projecting off your entities or querying your datastore directly.

```
public class PostDto
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string CategorySlug { get; set; }

    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public string TagSlug { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it will eliminate SELECT *, but PostDTO doesn't belong to the Model conceptually, so it shouldn't be used in my repositories to query the DB, should it?

Comment: It belongs to the ViewModel but no it should not be referenced in your Repositories. In CQS you don't use Repositories for populating ViewModels but rather a thin Query layer and Repositories are only used for write operations or Commands.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example - I would go with:

```
public class Post
{
    public Category Category {get;set;}
}
public class Tag
{
    public Post {get;set;}
}
```

That way it is far easier to query for exactly the tags you need for a given Post *when* you need them (You query Tag for those matching the Post instead of querying Post for Tags - thus giving you the abiltiy to page, filter etc. them).

As much as I can, I tend to avoid Collections (unless it is value objects that cannot exist without the parent object). It will be a lot easier to maintain in my experience.

And if you at some point need to show stats about your Post (how many tags it has attached and so on) - you can use 'views' of your data with just the data you need (equivalent to Views across tables in your DB). Views are outside your domain - thus you need not stick to the rules of your domain. Then when you go into 'edit mode' you load the full entity.

Comment: Thx for a tip, but it didn't answer my question. I'm asking if it's ok (from a view of "best practices") to perform SELECT * in order to have fully loaded entities which than have many data that I simply don't need (in my View).

Comment: The short answer is that it depends. Select * is only a problem if it is a problem (read: performance usually). Only do such optimizations if you are having problems.

Comment: Hmm, that's a second vote for "yes" to load all data... I'm starting to think I'm overprotective :)

Comment: Hehe - I've tried too many times to optimize before _knowing_ it was a problem only to learn that I won 5 ms in a 250 ms query after hours of hard work :).